# How to add the unit testing functionality in existing ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tdd

How to add the unit testing functionality (in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition) for an already existing ASP.NET MVC project?
I have added Test Project to achieve TDD but it looks entirely different. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that you want to unit test?

Comment: It looks entirely different compared to what?

Comment: [R# can help you generate unit tests for all existing action methods.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989900/how-can-i-create-nunit-tests-with-resharper) They won't be pretty though. :)

Comment: @Darin It comes with a solution Items folders which contains Local.testsettings, MVCApp.vsmdi, TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings files. Why these files are coming and what is the use of these files?

Comment: Those files are used to define different settings for the test project. Things like code coverage, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create empty project with unit test project and then add existing project to the current solution. Fix namespaces, type names (if needed) and that's it.

But you need to understand that you will have only couple sample tests and you will need to write your own to cover all code.