# How to use NUnit and not VisualStudio's UnitTestFramework

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper, resharper-8.0

I'm trying to create unit tests with resharper, but every time I click "create unit tests" it imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework and create MS unit tests. There is no option to use NUnit instead.

- I've disabled VisualStudio Testing Support in Resharper
- I deleted the MS UnitTest reference, but NUnit does not appear as a reference in the "Add reference" dialog
- I've manually added NUnit to my tests project with NuGet
- Resharper STILL uses VisualStudio's unit tests and imports the other DLL

Also,

- Resharper's website mostly talks about running tests, I do not have any tests yet
- I've tried searching but I seem to find information about how to run tests

So, if I have a class library. What are the exact steps I need to take to get Resharper to automatically create NUnit tests? I'm new to NUnit and fairly new to ReSharper so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use NUnit unit tests do the following:

- Add a Visual Studio C# Class Library project (don't use the Unit Test projects as they are designed to work with MSTest)
- Add NUnit references via NuGet

An example of the class structure will be:

```
using NUnit.Framework

namespace MyTest.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public void MyTests
    {
        [Test]
        UnitUnderTest_Scenario_ExpectedBehaviour()
        {
            // Test code goes here.
        }
    }
}
```

Resharper will decorate your tests with the green and yellow icons, see [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html) and [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Unit_Testing__Index.html) for more details.

Update: See [how Resharper can speed up the creation of unit tests](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Speed+up+creation+of+unit+tests).

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow when I have access to the code again. Do I have to create the first test just to have resharper create NUnit tests when I right click a class and select "Create Unit Tests?" I thought the reference alone would be good enough. But, I am using .NET 3.5 in my class library that I'm trying to test (it has to compile under the regular and compact framework). I don't care if the test library is .NET 4.0 or 3.5. I'm wondering if there's something preventing ReSharper from auto detecting the NUnit reference? I thought it came packaged with NUnit, but couldn't find it?

Comment: The "Create Unit Tests" context option seems to be part of Visual Studio (2010 only I think as it has been removed in 2012 and 2013), in which case it will create an MSTest rather than an NUnit one. You will have to create them manually as above.

Comment: Oh... I guess it is hard to tell. Yes, I was using VS2010. I finally found a question regarding the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989900/how-can-i-create-nunit-tests-with-resharper So with your comments, and finding this link: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Speed+up+creation+of+unit+tests I guess I have my answer